# SQL Query to identify records applicable for a distinct set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query that returns the result as shown below the query. However, I need only a subset of this data. I am interested in fetching DocumentIDs that are associated to RegionID value of 2 ONLY and not associated to any other region.

```
SELECT D.DocumentID, R.RegionID, COUNT(*) AS NUMOFPLANTSBYREGION 
FROM Document D INNER JOIN ShopAreaDoc SAD ON D.DocumentID = SAD.DocumentID 
INNER JOIN PlantShopAreaDoc PSAD ON SAD.ShopAreaDocID = PSAD.ShopAreaDocID 
INNER JOIN Plant P ON PSAD.PlantID = P.PlantID 
INNER JOIN Region R ON P.RegionID = R.RegionID 
GROUP BY D.DocumentID, R.RegionID 
ORDER BY D.DocumentID
```

## Query Results:

```
+------------+----------+---------------------+
| DocumentID | RegionID | NUMOFPLANTSBYREGION |
+------------+----------+---------------------+
|       2126 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2127 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2128 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2129 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2130 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2134 |        4 |                  13 |
|       2135 |        3 |                   8 |
|       2136 |        6 |                   9 |
|       2137 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2138 |        3 |                   8 |
|       2138 |        1 |                  20 |
|       2138 |        6 |                   9 |
|       2138 |        4 |                  14 |
|       2138 |        2 |                   8 |
|       2139 |        1 |                  17 |
|       2140 |        1 |                  17 |
+------------+----------+---------------------+
```

### The Result Set I am interested in as follows:

Other records are either not applicable to Region ID of 2 or applicable to more regions in addition to 2 and so should be excluded.

```
+------------+----------+----------------------+
| DocumentID | RegionID | NUMOFPLANTSBYREGION  |
+------------+----------+----------------------+
|       2126 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2127 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2128 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2129 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2130 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2137 |        2 |                    8 |
+------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and `not exists()`:

```
;with cte as (
  SELECT D.DocumentID, R.RegionID, COUNT(*) AS NUMOFPLANTSBYREGION 
  FROM Document D INNER JOIN ShopAreaDoc SAD ON D.DocumentID = SAD.DocumentID 
  INNER JOIN PlantShopAreaDoc PSAD ON SAD.ShopAreaDocID = PSAD.ShopAreaDocID 
  INNER JOIN Plant P ON PSAD.PlantID = P.PlantID 
  INNER JOIN Region R ON P.RegionID = R.RegionID
  GROUP BY D.DocumentID, R.RegionID 
)
select *
from cte
where not exists (
  select 1
  from cte i
  where i.DocumentID = cte.DocumentID
    and i.RegionID <> 2
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DUIE27467

returns:

```
+------------+----------+----------------------+
| DocumentID | RegionID | NUMOFPLANTSBYREGION  |
+------------+----------+----------------------+
|       2126 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2127 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2128 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2129 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2130 |        2 |                    8 |
|       2137 |        2 |                    8 |
+------------+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT D.DocumentID, R.RegionID, COUNT(*) AS NUMOFPLANTSBYREGION 
    FROM Document D 
    INNER JOIN ShopAreaDoc SAD ON D.DocumentID = SAD.DocumentID 
    INNER JOIN PlantShopAreaDoc PSAD ON SAD.ShopAreaDocID = PSAD.ShopAreaDocID 
    INNER JOIN Plant P ON PSAD.PlantID = P.PlantID 
    INNER JOIN Region R ON P.RegionID = R.RegionID 
    WHERE R.RegionId = 2
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Region R2 WHERE R2.RegionId <> 2 AND R2.DocumentId = D.documentid)
    GROUP BY D.DocumentID, R.RegionID 
    ORDER BY D.DocumentID
```

Comment: This will also return ID 2138 since it is part of both region 2 and 1 and 3 and 4 and 6, which OP wants to exclude as part of the requirements.

Comment: @JacobH Didn't notice those records. See revision.

Answer (score -1):

You may use this approach, implementing the MINUS statement (which does not exists in MySQL by the way):

```
SELECT DocumentID FROM docs WHERE RegionID=2 AND DocumentID NOT IN (SELECT DocumentID FROM docs WHERE RegionID<>2)
```

I also tried it on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66f0e8/57 and it seems to work.